# How to divide cell array into array and vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, split

This is my first time posting so i hope you can help me. I am trying to write a function in matlab.

I have laded data from a file into a cell array. First column contains statements and the second contains T for true og F for false. I now want to split this array into a cell array with the statements and a logical vector with 1 for True and -1 for false.

I use the fgetl within a loop to read all the lines into the cellarray

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it a bit more neatly next time, and consider including a small example.

Here is what you seem to be looking for:

Suppose you have a matrix `M` and want to split that into `M_true` and `M_false`

```
M = {1,'T';
22,'F';
333,'T'}

idx_T=strcmp(M(:,2),'T')

M_true = M(idx_T,1)
M_false = M(~idx_T,1)
```